# Show name of source table(s) in SELECT result

Tags: sql

I have a this simple sql script which I want to improve:

```
SELECT * FROM [arachnode.net].[dbo].[Schemes_Discoveries]
SELECT * FROM [arachnode.net].[dbo].[Hosts]
SELECT * FROM [arachnode.net].[dbo].[Extensions_Discoveries]
SELECT * FROM [arachnode.net].[dbo].[Domains_Discoveries]
SELECT * FROM [arachnode.net].[dbo].[Domains]
```

More select statements

I give an expected result. However I would like the name of the table to appear in the result, so that I may distinguish each result. I have already tried the: "as some-alias-table-name".

Thanks.

Comment: Tag with which SQL database you're using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, ...).

Comment: There's no built in function to do so (a la `DB_NAME()`) because in general, a single SQL `SELECT` may be composing results from multiple tables. As such, a simple solution like [Smandoli's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14585155/15498) may be the best fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, 'Schemes_Discoveries' FROM [arachnode.net].[dbo].[Schemes_Discoveries]
```

... with adjustments, possbily, depending on your database manager